# Elastic Beanstalk: ERROR: The EB CLI cannot find a platform for key "docker 17.03.1-ce"

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've recently been getting this error when trying to run an eb deploy command using the Elastic Beanstalk CLI. I cannot see any documentation around this issue.

Any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My ~/.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml and project .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml had different content. I needed to edit the entry for the project to change the default_platform entry to match my currently installed docker version.